# The method add(Component) is not applicable for the arguments

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to add a panel to my frame, but it keeps giving me one error that I don't seem to understand.

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - Debug Current Instruction Pointer
    - The method add(Component) in the type Container is
      not applicable for the arguments (TestPanel)
```

```java
import javax.swing.*;

public class FrameTest3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestPanel samplePanel=new TestPanel();
        JFrame sampleFrame = new JFrame();
        sampleFrame.getContentPane().add(samplePanel);
        sampleFrame.setSize(300,200);
        sampleFrame.setVisible(true);
        System.out.println("Done");
    } 
}
```

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestPanel extends JPanel {

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {   
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.drawString("hello", 30, 80);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Your code seems to work for me. Are these two classes in their own files? In the same package? Can you post the full error message with your question?

Comment: Working well for me too. Please provide more info about your error.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels These are two classes in the same package (default package) 
This is the full error message "Multiple markers at this line - Debug Current Instruction Pointer - The method add(Component) in the type Container is not applicable for the arguments (TestPanel)"

Comment: OK, do you have your **own** class nearby that you've named `JPanel`??

Comment: No i don't @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: OK, what happens if you place a `@Override` annotation above your `paintComponent` method (which should be `protected`, not `public` by the way)?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels same error

Comment: Then start over, re-compile, re-run.

Comment: Still doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

This complete, working example, based on your code, suggests that the problem is in your build environment.  In addition,

- `JFrame::add()` forwards to the contend pane implicitly.
- Construct and manipulate Swing GUI objects *only* on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).
- Don't use `setSize()` when you really mean to override [`getPreferredSize()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513).
- Invoke `super.paintComponent()` to avoid [visual artifacts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent-java.awt.Graphics-).
- For convenience in testing, a `private static` class is semantically equivalent to a [package-private](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) class.

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class FrameTest3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            TestPanel samplePanel = new TestPanel();
            JFrame sampleFrame = new JFrame();
            sampleFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            sampleFrame.add(samplePanel);
            sampleFrame.pack();
            sampleFrame.setVisible(true);
            System.out.println("Done");
        });
    }

    private static class TestPanel extends JPanel {

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.drawString("hello", 30, 80);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(300, 200);
        }
    }
}
```